# Windows CE OpenCV performance

Tags: windows, performance, stl, opencv

Im using OpenCV on Windows CE 6.0 R2 on and the performance is quite weak. I can do 300 YUV to RGB conversions per second (using my code), but OpenCV takes 3 seconds to perform a single cvGoodFeaturesToTrack() on a VGA image. I know OpenCV uses STL a lot, does anyone have experience with STL on Windows CE?

Thanks,
Filip

Comment: Which version of OpenCV?

Comment: How did you build OpenCV for Win CE on ARM4? I am trying to accomplish that very thing now and am having a rough time.

Comment: http://alexkarpus.com/opencv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvGoodFeaturesToTrack()` is a heavy function that uses a lot of floating point operations. If your platform does not support FP ops that would explain what your are seeing.
Try using the [FAST features](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=fast#cv-fast) which are, well, FAST.